# Is there any delay time when enconding to ogg vorbis in android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, encode, oggvorbis

I've been using oggvorbis libraries (found on google) to convert recordings made with my unity app.
While on the PC the code works fine and convert my recordings in 6 seconds approx, when i run the app on my android tablet the convertion turns to approx 30 seconds.
I haven't found text on any problem similar to mine.
Do you know if that behavior (delay in time)is normal when using that library? o could this be a problem related with my own code?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, unfortunately encoding to Vorbis is not accelerated on ARM devices.

Use AAC or AC3 encoding instead. Both Android and iOS provide accelerated encoding for those targets (realtime or better).